# How to read text from HTML input in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the webpage, the user is able to write text in a text field. I would like to use the button on this page to read this text and then place it somewhere else. Here is the simplified markup so far:

```
<div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
<h4>Let's make your Resume Header</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="header()" class="save">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript code that I have:

```
function header() {
  var name = document.getElementById(name).value;
  alert(name);
}
```

This alert does not work at all when I run it. I cannot figure out why, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Wrap the id in quotes

Comment: .getElementById("name")

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix. Thanks for the speedy reply. Much appreciated, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed quotes. So use `document.getElementById('name').value` instead of `document.getElementById(name).value`.

if you use `name` as a parameter then you can use it without quotes.

```js
function header() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
  <h4>Let's make your Resume Header</h4>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="name">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="header()" class="save">SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the elementById argument in quotes, as well as have a way for your HTML to reference your JavaScript. See Below.

```
<script>
function header() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  alert(name);
}
</script>

<div id="Demo1" class="w3-accordion-content w3-container">
<h4>Let's make your Resume Header</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="header()" class="save">SAVE</button>
</div>
```